# probability of intersection that is conditioned

Tags: probability

We have an urn with one white marble and another marble which is equally likely to be white or black. We sample twice with replacement. $W_i$ is the event that the $i$th draw is white. I have to find $P(W_2|W_1)$.

Define the event $A$ as "the second marble is white".
$P(W_1)$ is easy to find because I just break it up based on the partition $\{A,A^c\}$. But I'm having trouble with $P(W_1\cap W_2)$. If I try to break up using the same partition as before, then

$P(W_1\cap W_2)=P(W_1\cap W_2|A)P(A)+P(W_1\cap W_2|A^c)P(A^c)$

$=1/2[P(W_1\cap W_2|A)+P(W_1\cap W_2|A^c)]=1/2[1+P(W_1\cap W_2|A^c)]$

I want to make an independence assumption so that $P(W_1\cap W_2|A^c)=P(W_1|A^c)P(W_2|A^c)=1/4$. But suppose we can't make that assumption (because this problem occurs in the book prior to the section for independence). I want to find $P(W_1\cap W_2|A^c)$. My sample space has 5 elements (one for when the second marble is white, and 4 for when the second marble is black). Intuitively, the 4 elements when the second marble is black should all be equally likely. But I'm struggling to show it formally.

Comment: The key here is "with replacement." So you do indeed have the conditional independence that you want to suppose.